# Comparing two soccer team names in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I am trying to make a program that compares soccer team names from two different sites through Python.
My problem is that the names are not the exactly same.

For example on the first site a name is:

```
Liverpool Football Club
```

On the second site it's:

```
Liverpool FC
```

I've been trying to use the module: *fuzzywuzzy* and it's fuzz.ratio function but it doesn't really do the trick. If I put the fuzz.ratio at 30, it will match wrongly, and if I put fuzz.ratio too high it wont match rightly.

Is there a smarter way to match names in Python?

Comment: Are there many football team names that you are working with? If not, you could just manually marking them as equivalents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show your work?

I got the following:

```
>>> from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
>>> from fuzzywuzzy import process
>>> fuzz.ratio("Liverpool Football Club", "Liverpool FC")
69
```

That allows a higher threshold than 30